# What changes shall we make in the table

Tags: mysql

I was asked below question in an interview which i could not answer.Could anyone please help.

A primary school teacher wants to store the first name,last name,date of birth,gender(0=female and 1=male) and home phone number of each of her pupils in a MySQL database.She came up with the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE pupil(
pupil_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name CHAR(50),
last_name CHAR(50),
date_of_birth CHAR(50),
gender INT,
phone_number CHAR(50),
PRIMARY_KEY (pupil_id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

she frequently runs the following queries

```
select * from pupil where pupil_id = 2;
select * from pupil where first_name = 'John';
select * from pupil where first_name = 'John' and last_name = 'Doe';
```

What changes will you make to this table? and why?

Comment: when you frequently run searches on certain fields that implies you may want an index on said fields.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would have been I would add two indexes. One for first_name and one for first_name, last_name.

Answer (score 0):

If you frequently query according to the first name or the first and last names, it might be a good idea to index them:

```
CREATE INDEX pupil_names_ind ON pupil (first_name, last_name);
```

Having said that, you should really run a benchmark first. If the table has just a couple of hundreds of rows most of them will be caches anyway, and indexing it would be a wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index in the table in the columns `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
Syntax : CREATE INDEX `ind` ON `table`(`col`);
```

This will make the searches on the indexed columns fast. Go through this article => [When to use indexes?](http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases) and [MySQL's docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html). Basically you use indexes on frequently searched items to boost the performance. But remember one thing : Too many indexes slow insertions into the table. So, an effective usage of indexes will definitely speed up a query.

Answer (score 0):

You just want one index

```
CREATE INDEX pupils_by_name ON pupil (first_name, last_name)
```

first query(by id) is optimised thanks to primary key

second query(by first name) is handled by pupils_by_name index, because it fits the index column orders starting from left hand side, if you would want to optimise a query by 'last_name' field, this index would't work because the order of columns in where clause must match an order of columns in and index starting from the left

thrid query fits the index pupils_by_name perfectly

in addition

date_of_birth CHAR(50)   should be  date

gender INT  should be tinyint

Answer (score 0):

I would create indexes on the first_name and last_name (in that order). it is important. more info here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Then i would change the date_of_birth datatype to date